# How to remove whitespace around audio tag in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I am wondering where the white space around the audio tag in IE is coming from. I cant seem to pin point it. Is this a known issue?

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

In action: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6z9L/)

using: IE10

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: no whitespace for me in FF...

Comment: No whitespace in Chrome either...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Did you zero out the margins and paddings on elements such as body/html?

the `normalize.css` on jsfiddle zeros it out on some elements but doesn't include `html` in there.

Try putting `* { margin:0; padding:0; }` in the CSS.

Comment: Do you have a barebones example page, not within the context of JSFiddle? Stupid idea but try clearing out the whitespace inside of the element before/after the `source` tags? Nothing is getting inherited from other stylesheets for the audio element?

Comment: I'm working locally right now jsFiddle is my only option to show. I tried clearing before and after. Nothing is getting inherited, I have reproduced without calling any styles and just using the audio tag alone.